# ANT Generated jar: is it a namespace issue?

Tags: ant, jar, export

I have a Eclipse-Java-Project with an ANT-build-file. This build file exports a jar of the project without compiling it. So I only export the sources.

```
<target name="jar">
    <mkdir dir="/jar"/>
    <jar destfile="/jar/my_test_jarfile.jar" basedir="/src" />
</target>
```

I use this generated jar in another eclipse java project and set the path to the jar in the build-path-settings of the project. The problem is that eclipse says it cannot resolve the namespace of the imported classes of the jar.
If I export the jar manually by right clicking on the project and then "Export" and putting the jar to the build path of the other project, everything works fine and there are no errors. So the question is now, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: re:formatting. i think the issue was that you need a new line between where your non-code ends and your code begins.
after that, can you add the specific error stack that you get? and apologies for asking this, but did you use a tool like BeyondCompare to validate that the two generated JARs are identical? or even just making sure they're the same size? and - again apologies - but is the jar that ANT generates the same name as the one you generate manually? i ask only because the classloader can create race conditions as it loads the files in alpha order (i believe).

Comment: Thanks for formatting. what do you mean by new line between non-code and code? I used such a tool and there are a lot of differences, but you can't read them, i think it is binary. they both have the same name. Maybe you can give an ant example where it creates exactly the same jar as if you right click on the project and then export.

Comment: okay, seems that i solved it on my own. i had to compile it first. i thought only sources would be fine too. but now it works. thanks anyway!

Comment: re:code/non-code ... if you hit 'edit' on your post you can see that there's now a blank line after your "So I only export the sources" and where your ANT code begins. SO doesn't recognize code snippets unless there's an empty line preceding the snippet. as far as your issue goes, good find. honestly i looked right past that ... silly of me to miss the missing javac task.

Comment: also, you can feel free to post your fix as an answer and then mark it as "the answer." i think given your rep you may have to wait a couple days to mark your own answer as the answer, but in the interest of completeness it would be nice to be able to mark the question as "answered".

Comment: i can accept my own answer in 7 hours it says. so i'll do it in 7 hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is my solution. It seems that you have to compile the source first and then pack it into a jar. I don't give a guarantee that this jar is exactly the same like the one you get from eclipse when you do the right click thing and export etc.
But it works for me, there are no namespace errors any longer. so here is a minimum version of my ant targets:

```
<project default="run" basedir=".">
    <property name="src.dir" value="src" />
    <property name="classes.dir" value="bin" />
    <property name="build.dir" value="build" />

    <path id="libs">
        <fileset dir="lib">
            <include name="*.jar"/>
        </fileset>
        <pathelement path="${basedir}\${classes.dir}"/>
    </path>

    <target name="run">
        <antcall target="compile"/>
        <antcall target="jar"/>
    </target>

    <target name="compile">
        <javac debug="true" srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${classes.dir}" classpathref="libs" encoding="UTF-8" />
    </target>

    <target name="jar">
        <jar destfile="${build.dir}/my_jar_file.jar" basedir="${classes.dir}"> 
    </target>
</project>
```